# question mark in visual studio debugger

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS 2010 to program in C++.
In debug mode I usually am able to see the content every object/container that I am using, even the ones that comes from the STL. Except that for the following "Entity_set_z_ordered" set, I am unable to see the content of my container, in debug mode it just shows a "?"

```
struct z_orderer {
        bool operator() ( const Entity* lhs, const Entity* rhs) const{
            return (lhs->getPosition().y < rhs->getPosition().y || ( (lhs->getPosition().y == rhs->getPosition().y) && lhs->getPosition().x < rhs->getPosition().x));
        }
    };
std::set<Entity*, z_orderer> Entity_set_z_ordered;
```

Any idea of where this is coming from or how I could debug this? I haven't changed any of the default Debug setting

thanks

edit : I solved it, the problem was that  struct z_orderer was defined inside my main function and not outside of it. I'm not sure if this would have created problems during runtime, but at least I can debug it now!

Comment: A ? indicates a pointer to unmapped memory.  Use Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory1 to verify.

Comment: How can I verify if the memory is unmapped? 
starting from the adress of my set I have this:
0x0023AFE4  58 5c ae 08 cc cc cc cc 60 57 ae 08 00 00  
0x0023AFF2  00 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc  
0x0023B000  cc cc cc 01 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc  
0x0023B00E  cc 01 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 01  
0x0023B01C  cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 01 cc cc  
0x0023B02A  cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 00 cc cc cc cc  
0x0023B038  cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc  
0x0023B046  cc cc cc cc cc 00 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc  
0x0023B054  98 54 ae 08 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 30 4a

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that stumbles across this... this happened to me when I had 
a getter property in a class model pointing to itself.  It was a copy paste error, notice the property name below is ShouldNotProcess, and in the getter it's returning itself.  The return was supposed to be: return !this.**ShouldProcess;**

```
public bool ShouldNotProcess
{
    get { return !this.ShouldNotProcess; }
}
```