# Get question mark instead property name and value in Debug Mode in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

My issue is: during Debug Mode in Visual Studio I can not see property name and it value. Any suggestions? **UPD This bug/feature is reproducible in college PC.**
[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPD(15.06.2012)**

The base class is placed to separated lib. Base class is abstract. And... Two times Debug was working fine, after making changes in source file (in screen-shots) and then running the project.

Please notice that Immediate window can not evaluate this expression.

MailProcessingViewModelContext inherits that base class that I have mentioned in the top of UPD.

Comment: Looks like the debugging symbols aren't loaded for that object...but that's just a guess

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the `MailProcessingViewModelContext`? It might help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: This problems seems to exist in VS2013 and VS2015. The only difference is the entire debugging session crashes. Using the arrow buttons or arrow keys does not solve the crashing. The Locals and Watch windows also crash the debugging session.

Answer (score 13):

It's a bug in Visual Studio that's caused when you scroll through the properties list with a mouse. Click the down arrow at the bottom of the menu instead.

Comment: I've experienced this in VS2010 and VS2012. Verified that clicking the down arrow or presssing the down arrow key displays the members and values.

Comment: Relavent connect reports: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/547872/debugger-instance-variable-inspection-displays-some-instance-fields-and-then-shows http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/details/769019

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem. Strangely, it happen on one machine, but another one with same version of Visual Studio just work fine.

Comment: Matt, what down arrow are you referring to? I'm having the same issue in VS2015.

Comment: @silkfire It's been a long time since I posted this answer, but it sounds like I meant the down arrow on the scrollbar. If you have too few properties for it to be scrollable, then I doubt this bug is causing your particular issue. Remember that the problem occurs when you scroll a long list of properties *using the mouse*. I believe that using the scrollbar's up-and-down-arrows to scroll instead is what resolved the issue for me, and others.

Answer (score 1):

As somebody on top already mentioned, you need the debugging symbol files (.pdb's) for every dll that you are using which is not your code, otherwise VS can't look 'inside'.

and if it's obfuscated you won't see anything at all

Comment: Possible you are right, and I should recheck. But All code is mine. And I am not using obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if you were debugging an ASP.NET wizard and wanted to check a collection of something, all elements in the collection that are in the current wizard step (current context) would be visible while the others are there but not in context just now hence marked as questionmarks -> ?

Maybe it could be something like that in your case. I guess it could be the same scenario

Answer (score 1):

For me, this happened when I had a getter property in a class model pointing to itself.  It was a copy paste error, notice the property name is ShouldNotProcess, and in the getter it's returning itself.  The return was supposed to be: return !this.**ShouldProcess;**

```
public bool ShouldNotProcess
{
    get { return !this.ShouldNotProcess; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to debug your own code or someone else's?

If it's not your code, the code has probably been obfuscated so you cannot see the private members or use reflector to reverse engineer it.

This also might happen if you're using a trackpad to scroll through the member list. Try using the keyboard instead.

Comment: I managed to reproduce your problem wheb using the trackpad on my laptop to scroll the members list. If you're using a trackpad try using the keyboard or a mouse wheel to scroll.

Comment: I am using mouse, just clicks.

Comment: Three cheers for Windows debugging and mouse scrolling display bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access these menu items or display these windows in design mode. To display these menu items, the debugger must be running or in break mode.

REF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhawk8xd

Comment: I am running my app. Then breakpoint hit and I get that result.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility that the object you are referring to belongs to another project (library template) and you added it as a file reference and not project reference?

Please share the details about the structure of the projects in your solution. Also the location of the class you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running in debug mode, I know I'm probably stating the obvious there. Also, check that expression you're evaluating - is it right? Are you casting to the right object. Finally, is the assembly that contains the class you are looking at included as a project in the solution, or just referenced as an external assembly? Make sure it's part of the sln.

If it's recreatable on another copy of visual studio then I'd guess it's not a problem with Visual Studio, but the object you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case in your situation, but here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438087/question-mark-in-visual-studio-debugger) with a similar issue.  Hope it helps

Comment: The link was attached to the word post in my answer, does it not appear for you as a link, if not here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438087/question-mark-in-visual-studio-debugger

Comment: Sorry. I did not see that you had hyperlinked the word 'post'. My mistake.