# C#, .getDirectories(string file) issue retrieving directories

Tags: c#, file, directory

I am trying to retrieve the subdirectories of a path I pass in. It proccess it and gives me half of the subdirectories but for the other half, it returns a "?" when debugging. I do not know what is causing this
Here is what I have:

```
 string root = @"C:\Users\Documents\Meta Consumer";
 string[] subDir = Directory.GetDirectories(root);
```

When Debugging:

1: (good)

2: (good)

3: (good)

..  ..

?: (this is where 14 is)

?: (15 is here)

..  ..

?: ?

Comment: Looks like an instance of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918981/get-question-mark-instead-property-name-and-value-in-debug-mode-in-visual-studio

Comment: You could add a search parameter and specify `AllDirectories` or `TopLevelDirectory` like so: `string [] subDir = Directory.GetDirectories(root, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`  Then actually write a `foreach loop` to return those values.

Comment: I run your exact code and pull from my `Users\Documents\somepathwithsubfolders` and it works fine.. perhaps you need to run Visual Studio in Admin mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the entire goal, if you intend to specifically *Search* for a specific item or intend to manipulate the *Directory* at all.  One thing that I do see is you haven't specified any additional search for your array.  This can be hindered I believe through deep nesting or permission issues.

*Resolution One*:  Ensure that you have valid permission to do recursive searches within the specified directory.

*Resolution Two*: You can attempt to run a search for all items with a *wildcard* then force it to search all directories.  This may help solve potential deep nesting issues you may encounter.

*Resolution Three*:  Try the below code; see if it solves the issue.

```
string root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Documents);
string[] subDir = Directories.GetDirectories(root, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string s in subDir)
{
     Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

See if that returns the proper information that it wasn't previously.  There are folders located in your *Library* that though are considered public to the user are still locked as they reside in the *User Profile* so permissions will be a good check.

Running Visual Studio as an Administrator will also help in your troubleshooting.  Also you should see if there are any `Inner Exceptions` to help identify it as well.