# Arrays won't go past 14

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, debugging, limit

I have this code:

```
int[] numbers = new int[1000];
```

When I debug in Visual Studios and hover my mouse over the num array it shows the length is 1000 and then the first 14 characters are 0 and everything after that is a "?".

[image: StupidArrays]

Assigning numbers[15]+ doesn't change anything nor does it crash the program.

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: in watch window type numbers[15], what is output of that?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918981/get-question-mark-instead-property-name-and-value-in-debug-mode-in-visual-studio)?

Comment: Restart and then check

Comment: @JMK :  you can see the code in his image (`int[] numbers= new int[1000]`)

Comment: The value of those elements aren't `?` which is why the `?` is a replacement for the element and value. If you wish to see the actual value of any specific element àt in dex X you can do `numbers[x]` in the watch window.

Comment: Maybe 14 is the [largest number](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D4J9MRYJz9-4&ei=FkKDUsrPD8L0kQXpz4DgAw&usg=AFQjCNHv5fEonIuF6xyRTk_UXifGgjUUZw&sig2=updM4q_F9cciS1D_hXaZ1w&bvm=bv.56343320,d.dGI)?

Comment: @MikeGoodwin I was interested in how the values in the array were being set, but link from CodeCaster sounds like the solution anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out!

Thanks to @CodeCaster

It is just a bug in visual studios that glitches the values out. Just using the mouse over the arrows at the bottom work.