# Array in my debug mode only display first 14 elements and the rest are display (?) question mark

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64

I am using windows 7 x64.

I happens to notice this problem yesterday.

In the code, I have a array of type int and size 500, or anything actually and X > 14

I am using a for loop to put number into that array. And, I set a debug break point at the end of the loop to look at the element in the array.

But, only the 0-14 elements of the array show has number and the rest show question marks?

However, if I were to print the array, I can see values in all of them.

I am using the Visual Studio 2012 Express mode.

I set debug mode to be Any CPU. I tried x64 and x86 also, but I have the same problem.

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a (silly) bug in Visual Studio that's caused when you scroll through the debug view of the list with your mouse. To "remedy" it, use/click the down arrow at the bottom of the menu instead of using the mouse to scroll.

**EDIT**

[See this for a similar/same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918981/get-question-mark-instead-property-name-and-value-in-debug-mode-in-visual-studio)

Comment: wow, i can't believe this bug exist. but yeah, you are right that if i click down, i am able to see data in the array.
But, how can I fix this problem permanent?

Comment: Not sure that you can. :S