# Create array - Visual Studio shows question marks

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio

I have problem with array creation in C#.

```
        String[] tempDateLine = new String[dataImport.nbrLines];
```

The syntax is (for me) right and the dataImport.nbrLines value is 23 (debugger).

But in the debugger I see :

[image]

After the index 14 I have problem for initialize my array and during the assignment I haven't error but no value is imported in my array (above 14).

Comment: Without seeing more of your code it's nearly impossible to tell you what, if anything, you missed.

Comment: What is the type of dataImport.nbrLines ?

Comment: `public int nbrLines;`

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411433/array-in-my-debug-mode-only-display-first-14-elements-and-the-rest-are-display)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is the bug of Visual Studio, and you should use down arrow instead of mouse scrolling. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918981/get-question-mark-instead-property-name-and-value-in-debug-mode-in-visual-studio) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411433/array-in-my-debug-mode-only-display-first-14-elements-and-the-rest-are-display) ask the same problem.